# Kusto :can we use table columns to query parameter

Tags: kql

I have two table:
Table1=(Vin,Start_time,End_time)
Table2=(Vin,Timestamp)

I want to read all records from Table 1 where start and end time match with Table1.
So I tried below query.

```
//Running
declare query_parameters(start_Time:datetime = datetime(2021-03-18T08:49:08.467Z),end_Time:datetime =datetime(2021-03-18T13:32:28Z));
let q1=ABC
| where Vin == 'ABC' and Start_Time == start_Time and End_Time== end_Time
| project   Vin,Start_Time,End_Time,Total_packets=round(Minutes/5,0),Minutes;
let q2=PQR
| where Vin == 'ABC' and Timestamp >start_Time and Timestamp < end_Time
|summarize Events=count() by Vin,start_Time,end_Time
| project Vin,start_Time,end_Time,Events;
q2
| join q1 on Vin,$left.Vin == $right.Vin,$left.start_Time==$right.Start_Time,$left.end_Time==$right.End_Time
|project Vin,start_Time,end_Time,Events,Minutes,Total_packets;
```

This query work fine but this is for for static datetime. and I want to read start and end time from ABC table as query parameter.
Otherwise help me how to compare this timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate start_time and end_time based on some query. Here's an example for some calculation, which you should put before your query:

```
let start_Time = toscalar(MyTable | where <...> | summarize min(Timestamp));
let end_Time = toscalar(MyTable | where <...> | summarize max(Timestamp));
```

Note the use of [`toscalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction) around the query that calculates start_Time and end_Time. It's needed because a query returns a tabular result (with one column and one record), while what you want is a scalar (of type datetime). This is exactly what `toscalar` does.

Comment: Can we iterate on this two columns?

Comment: let start_Time = toscalar(MyTable | where Vin == 'ABC' |project Start_Time);                    
 >>This is work fine bt this variable read only one row i want to read full columns and compare that column with query

Comment: You cannot use something like foreach on a column, and call a function that receives scalars and returns a tabular result (because this would've been very inefficient). But depending on what exactly you need, this can usually be done efficiently in another way. Please create a new question with sample minimal input (in datatable format), provide the expected output, and an explanation on how the output is supposed to be produced, and we'll try to assist.